# Cutting a hole using a boolean still shows up in a 3D print

Tags: modifiers

Im trying to model an RC Car rim, and I need to cut a hole in the middle of the hex joint, and I've been using a Boolean, which has been working great. But when I export it as an .stl file, and load it into Cura, its fine. But when I slice it, it acts as if the cylinder is still there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you applied the boolean modifier?

Comment: I have, but I think I stuffed something else up. I think its the hexagon-it still thinks there's a face there. I'm going to remodel that inner section again and see what happens.

Comment: If you still have a problem, consider uploading the blend file to [blend exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)